# Pivot Tables crashing Excel 2013

Tags: pivot-table, excel-2013

I have a couple of issues I have been able to replicate on multiple machines (all running Office 2013 either as standard or as part of a 365 sub. 3 running W7 and one on W8.1)

Whenever I load certain sheets with pivot tables, I can refresh data on them and that all works OK, but if I show the "Field List" bar on the right, Excel grinds to a halt and will not accept any input. Another, possibly related, issue is on some (not on all the ones with the first issue though) I use freeze panes. When refreshing the ones with this active, the screen flashes rather a lot and only stops when I turn off Freeze Panes.

Have tried various fixes such as setting Windows to "Best Performance", disabling Hardware Acceleration in Excel, disabling addins (it does the same things using /safe) and recreating the file from scratch (this works the first time I use it, but then if it gets opened in 2007 Excel, then opened again in 2013, the issue comes back again), disabling animations with a registry tweak and renaming the OSF.dll file.

Have checked and am running latest update of Office 2013 (currently 15.0.4675.1002).

Comment: Bit more diagnosis: It only occurs when in Page Break view. If I do it in Normal view, there is no issue whatsoever

Comment: Scratch that. Just replicated in Normal View too

Comment: The issue seems to be more related to if a print area is set from what I have seen now. I have been trying to replicate the crash when removing the print area and have been unable to. If the print area only partly encompasses the Pivot Table then it also works fine, but if the print area is just the size of the pivot table then it crashes (and if freeze panes is on, it causes the flashing so it seemingly is related). If I extend the print area by one row and one column outside of the pivot table, from what I have seen it has not crashed.

Comment: okay, so I had the same issue but I was using the Excel Tables in MS 2013 as the Pivot source. As soon as I converted the table to regular cell ranges it seems to work fine.